# Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_id' in

Tags: php, post, warnings, offset

why am i getting this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\Rozary.php on line 385?

this is my code

```
$login = new LogIn();
$user_data = $login->check_login($_SESSION['rozary_user_id']);

$post = new Post();
$id = $user_data['user_id'];
$posts = $post->get_posts($id);
if ($posts) {             
    foreach ($posts as $ROW) {
        $user = new User(); //line 384
        $ROW_USER = $user->get_user($ROW['user_id']);  //line 385
        include ("post.php");  //line 386
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 385?

Comment: $ROW_USER = $user->get_user($ROW['user_id']);

Comment: Then the problem is that `$ROW` is a string, not an array.

Comment: so how can i change $ROW to array ?

Comment: You need to call a different method than `get_posts`, since that just returns an array of strings. You need to call something that returns a 2-dimensional array that includes information like the user_id.

Comment: Isn't the userid for the posts the same as `$id`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/27678436#27678436

Comment: $id contain userid of user data. all users have some data like id,userid,username,email,password,.....etc. so $id contain userid and used for posting and display friends if i want.